# Sublimetext swift plugin doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2, swift

I installed swift plugin with package controller https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Swift

I restarted and opened a .swift file but I got no syntax highlighting why isn't the purpose of this plugin?

I use sublimetext 2.0.2 for windows.

Comment: Are you able to manually select "Swift" for syntax highlighting at the bottom-right corner of the window? If not, then the package is probably not installed correctly.

Comment: You can check for issues on the project page or file your own.  Better yet, you can fix it and send a pull request.

Comment: @jewirth thanks I didn't realize I had to choose swift : I thought sublimetext would recognize the .swift extension

Comment: @user310291: it should so... are you sure the filename is correct? Maybe it's something like file.swift.txt and the explorer hides the .txt part

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to [this github URL](https://github.com/quiqueg/Swift-Sublime-Package)

Step 2: Click on 'clone or download' button.

Step 3: Restart your sublime and type cltr+shift+p and start typing "install" in suggestions click on "Package control: Install Package".

Step 4: Then type swift and select first suggestion and then press enter

(Optional) Step 5: In menu bar select view -> syntax -> swift and it's done.

Note: The same steps can be followed for all other language packages but only the URL in step 1 will be different.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the package after you download the package. Follow this instruction! good luck!

[image]